# Why This alert not working

Tags: jquery, html

> I Want to see true on the alert why its not working

```
<input type="button" class="checkButtonRed"id="s0" value="stack" style="font-size:large;font-weight:bold" />

int i =  0;

alert($('#' + 's' + i).hasClass("checkButtonRed"));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sc9gtkrx/1/

Comment: Check the JS console and see you have *syntax* error

Comment: JS uses `var`, not `int`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no `int` (or other variable types) in Javascript. You want:

```
var i = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

var i=0;

alert($("#s" + i).hasClass(" checkButtonRed "));

Comment: First you decide when you want to show this alert and provide space in before id attribute and make int to var bcz in javascript every think is var.

Comment: 1. I'm not OP 2. Your current answer is simply wrong.

Comment: Hv you try my answer

Comment: 1. I'm not OP 2. There is already a correct answer that was given 10 minutes before yours. PS: please stop using "hv", "bcz" and so on.